# What is the meaning of @jls in javadoc?

Tags: java, javadoc

- @jls 4.3.2. The Class Object
- @jls 9.8 Functional Interfaces
- @jls 9.4.3 Interface Method Body
- @since 1.8
  */

Found this javadoc in some core java classes, what is meaning of this? when to use in writing javadoc?

Answer (score 12):

`@jls` indicates a reference to a section of the [*Java Language Specification*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/).

See for example:

- [4.3.2 The Class Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.2)
- [9.8 Functional Interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.8)
- [9.4.3 Interface Method Body](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4.3)

The last annotation in your question, `@since`, is used to indicate the Java version (`1.8` being Java 8) in which the documented class or method was first made available.

Comment: Thank you , that means I have to read a lot of Java Language specification.

Comment: As anyone should from time to time :)